# Resolution to unexpected "Profiles/MDM wants to make changes." popups? Beware SpamResponse/wmcglobal?

Tags: security, malware, mdm, configuration-profiles, alert

I'm frequently getting unexpected "Profiles/MDM wants to make changes." popups.
It started right after I began installing [SpamResponse](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/spamresponse/id1439469017) by clicking GET, but aborted when it prompted to install a profile, and I changed my mind after noticing that and noticing it has no (visible) ratings and has received no updates for 2 years...

Any troubleshooting or cleanup ideas?  (I'm running a malware scan.)
The only profile on my system is XFINITY, and it's verified, expected, and wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.  Did some troubleshooting.

Opened Console.app and turned on logging just before closing the pop-up, and searched for MDM and found this, among other things: error 21:58:36.710797-0800 mdmclient [ERROR] **Error auto removing profile: XFINITY WiFi** (1E8E0793-8F17-4B01-990E-F36652D11CA7:0867CB49-D772-4E0C-A91B-D3B5DCEBBC0D) (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-128 "**userCanceledErr**"). No idea why it's trying to remove it, but I removed it manually to see if that helps. (If not I could put it back after.)

After removing it, I found and followed the instructions at https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/wifi-for-mac. This enhances Wi-Fi security by making WPA2-encrypted public XFINITY Wi-Fi connections usable or better - I forget which. I prefer installing just the profile to installing a huge app, and easier once you have found the source for the profile download - which I'm linking to. It does require a valid Xfinity login.
(I also did a malware scan, which found nothing.)  However, I accidentally clicked on the prompt which popped up twice during the process, so ... uncertain as to what the fix was.